# Sitecore User Group Poland (SUGPL) - 23 March 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed

- Date/Time (local): Friday, 23 March 2018 at 5:30pm
- Date/Time (UTC): Friday, 23 March 2018 at 4:30pm
- Location: 1 Sierpnia 8, Bulding A, Warsaw, Poland
- Event details: [meetup details and registration](https://www.facebook.com/events/210134069569076/)
- Contact: [sugpl.info](http://sugpl.info/en/contact/)
- Streaming: yes, link will be published on Sitecore Slack 1 hour before the even
- Sponsors: intive, Netcompany
- Presentations:

  - "Connecting frontend and backend using NitroNet Sitecore." - Dawid Jachowicz from Unic
  - "Headless CMS. Sitecore JSS getting started, tips and tricks" - Artsem Prashkovich & Ihar Pauliuk from Brimit
  - "SXA in real life example" - Szymon Kuźniak from intive

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion has begun